# had vs have difference?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

What's the difference between :

> I have not sent this email.
>   I had not sent this email.

I usually get confused in had/have. And I might have used them incorrectly many times. Can someone explain what to use when with some examples?

Comment: Hi, lea - have you read about the difference between [present perfect](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/) and the [past perfect](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/)?

Comment: I do know the difference but when it comes to implementing these rules I get confused and sometimes use the wrong tense in the flow. But thanks for the link I will again look at the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not sent the email

means that, as of right now, the email is not sent. If someone asks you the question: "Have you sent the email?", this is your response.

> I had not sent the email

means that, at some point in the past, based on the context of the conversation, the email was not sent. If someone asked you: "did you send the email before the deadline yesterday?", this would be your response.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification. This helped me understand the concept. Can you please give an example of this response - I sent the email.